# ArcPy SignInToPortal() Error "Failed to sign out"

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-pro, arcgis-portal

Does anyone know how to sign out of portal using arcpy?

The code below let me sign into portal. Running the script anytime after that causes an error "Failed to sign out". That tells me that it is probably signed into portal but I haven't found a way to sign out. The error traceback is below.

Things I tried:

- SignOutFromPortal_server() gives the error. "module 'arcpy' has no
  attribute 'SignOutFromPortal_server'". Was this ported to Pro?
- Catching the error works but it's a problem if my portal name or
  credentials are different than the one that's currently signed in.
- Using ProPy.bat gives the same error.
- Adding an 'r' before the portal string gives the same error.
- Closing everything and logging out of the server changes nothing.
- Here is an [ESRI Community post](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/arcpy-signintoportal-quot-failed-to-sign-out-quot-error/td-p/1023642) with a very similar title but the
  answer provided was not helpful.

This is running from in IDLE Python 3.7.9 [MSC v.1922 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

ArcGIS Server 10.8.1

```
import arcpy

# This returns "https://gisproweb01p.houtx.lcl/cohportal/"
ptl = arcpy.GetActivePortalURL()

arcpy.SignInToPortal("https://gisproweb01p.houtx.lcl/cohgis", "domain\user", "xxxxxx")

more code...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\Workspace\Locators\test_batch\BARC_batch\BARC_Geocode.py", line 25, in <module>
    arcpy.SignInToPortal(r"https://gisproweb01p.houtx.lcl/cohgis", "ZZZZZZZZZZZZ", "XXXXX")
  File "M:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 2450, in SignInToPortal
    return _SignInToPortal(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: Failed to sign out.
```

Comment: Any update on it? Facing similar issue...